# React render DOM HTML page in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React app, I am using the standard component. However, when the user clicks a save & exit option they should be redirected to a page which is a dom element from an outside location:
`document.getElementById('thank-you')`

I've created a component which should display this page:
**RedirectComponent**

```
const Redirect = () => {
  return (
      <div
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: window.document.getElementById('save-landing-page'),
        }}
      />
  );
};
```

I thought that setting this to display inner HTML as shown in the code below would result in the display of my element as the first error I got suggested I use an array (which the data is not)

However,where the component should be rendered, I only see the following text:

`[object HTMLElement]`

How can I display this external page in my React Component?

Comment: Did you try adding ```innerHTML``` at the end like ```window.document.getElementById('save-landing-page').innerHTML``` ?

Comment: @ManirajMurugan I added it and it worked. Can you add this as the solution?

Comment: What is a DOM element from an outside location? Sounds like a Steven Spielberg movie. `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is intended to render html markup, a string that contains markup, not DOM elements. Also when you say *redirect* it doesn't seem you mean what the term is used for.

Comment: @NoblePolygon, Added as solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line of code,

```
<div
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
   __html: window.document.getElementById('save-landing-page'),
 }}
/>
```

-> You are assigning the `HTMLElement` as the HTML value which won't work.

-> And that is the reason you are hetting `[object HTMLElement]` as result.

-> Instead you need to assign the `HTML` that you get from `window.document.getElementById('save-landing-page')` .

-> For which you need to assign `innerHTML` of the element.

So change,

```
window.document.getElementById('save-landing-page')
```

**to:**

```
window.document.getElementById('save-landing-page').innerHTML
```